# You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries. Bug reports are welcome

Tags: ruby, cocoapods

```
Analyzing dependencies
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/classes.rb:36: [BUG] Illegal instruction at 0x0000000102818000
ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:                    
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports                                     
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports                                      
   for more details.                                                        
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file in bug reports.     

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0054 p:---- s:0314 e:000313 CFUNC  :getdtablesize
c:0053 p:0050 s:0310 e:000309 CLASS  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/classes.rb:36
.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/classes.rb:3:in `<module:Ethon>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/classes.rb:27:in `<module:Curl>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/classes.rb:36:in `<class:FDSet>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon/curls/classes.rb:36:in `getdtablesize'

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: /usr/local/bin/pod

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 thread.rb
    2 rational.so
    3 complex.so
    4 
  337 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/nodes/alias.rb
  338 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/nodes.rb
  339 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/streaming.rb
  340 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb
  341 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb
  342 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/visitors/emitter.rb
  343 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/handler.rb
  344 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/tree_builder.rb
  345 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb
  346 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/json/ruby_events.rb
  347 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/visitors/json_tree.rb
  348 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/visitors/depth_first.rb
  349 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/visitors.rb
  350 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/parser.rb
  351 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/coder.rb
  352 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/core_ext.rb
  353 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/stream.rb
  354 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/json/yaml_events.rb
  355 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/json/tree_builder.rb
  356 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/json/stream.rb
  357 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych/handlers/document_stream.rb
  358 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb
  359 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/yaml.rb
  360 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb
  361 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/version.rb
  362 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/errors.rb
  363 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/event.rb
  364 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/concern/dereferenceable.rb
  365 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/concern/obligation.rb
  366 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/logger.rb
  367 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/concern/logging.rb
  368 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/concern/deprecation.rb
  369 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/executor_service.rb
  370 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/abstract_executor_service.rb
  371 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/serial_executor_service.rb
  372 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/immediate_executor.rb
  373 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/delay.rb
  374 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic_reference/numeric_cas_wrapper.rb
  375 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic_reference/mutex_atomic.rb
  376 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/atomic_reference.rb
  377 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_executor_service.rb
  378 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/monotonic_time.rb
  379 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb
  380 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/thread_pool_executor.rb
  381 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/cached_thread_pool.rb
  382 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/processor_counter.rb
  383 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/configuration.rb
  384 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/mutex_atomic_boolean.rb
  385 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/atomic_boolean.rb
  386 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/utility/native_integer.rb
  387 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/mutex_atomic_fixnum.rb
  388 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/atomic_fixnum.rb
  389 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/cyclic_barrier.rb
  390 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/mutex_count_down_latch.rb
  391 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/java_count_down_latch.rb
  392 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/count_down_latch.rb
  393 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/read_write_lock.rb
  394 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/abstract_thread_local_var.rb
  395 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/ruby_thread_local_var.rb
  396 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/java_thread_local_var.rb
  397 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/thread_local_var.rb
  398 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/reentrant_read_write_lock.rb
  399 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/mutex_semaphore.rb
  400 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/semaphore.rb
  401 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomics.rb
  402 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/fixed_thread_pool.rb
  403 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/simple_executor_service.rb
  404 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/indirect_immediate_executor.rb
  405 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/java_executor_service.rb
  406 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/java_single_thread_executor.rb
  407 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/java_thread_pool_executor.rb
  408 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_single_thread_executor.rb
  409 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb
  410 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/serialized_execution.rb
  411 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/serialized_execution_delegator.rb
  412 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/single_thread_executor.rb
  413 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/collection/copy_on_write_observer_set.rb
  414 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/collection/copy_on_notify_observer_set.rb
  415 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/concern/observable.rb
  416 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/ivar.rb
  417 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/options.rb
  418 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/scheduled_task.rb
  419 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/collection/java_non_concurrent_priority_queue.rb
  420 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/collection/ruby_non_concurrent_priority_queue.rb
  421 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/collection/non_concurrent_priority_queue.rb
  422 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/timer_set.rb
  423 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executors.rb
  424 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/atomic_markable_reference.rb
  425 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/agent.rb
  426 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atom.rb
  427 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/array.rb
  428 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/thread_safe/util/data_structures.rb
  429 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/set.rb
  430 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/tuple.rb
  431 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/async.rb
  432 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/future.rb
  433 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/dataflow.rb
  434 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/maybe.rb
  435 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/exchanger.rb
  436 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/abstract_struct.rb
  437 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/immutable_struct.rb
  438 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/mutable_struct.rb
  439 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/mvar.rb
  440 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promise.rb
  441 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/settable_struct.rb
  442 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/timer_task.rb
  443 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/tvar.rb
  444 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/collection/lock_free_stack.rb
  445 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/re_include.rb
  446 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promises.rb
  447 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/thread_safe/synchronized_delegator.rb
  448 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.9/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent.rb
  449 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb
  450 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/trunk_source.rb
  451 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb
  452 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/core_overrides.rb
  453 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods.rb
  454 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb
  455 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/errors.rb
  456 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/options/repo_update.rb
  457 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/options/project_directory.rb
  458 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/cache/list.rb
  459 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/cache/clean.rb
  460 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/cache.rb
  461 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/env.rb
  462 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/init.rb
  463 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb
  464 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/ipc/list.rb
  465 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/ipc/podfile.rb
  466 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/ipc/podfile_json.rb
  467 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/ipc/repl.rb
  468 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/ipc/spec.rb
  469 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/ipc/update_search_index.rb
  470 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/ipc.rb
  471 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/lib/create.rb
  472 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/lib/lint.rb
  473 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/lib.rb
  474 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/list.rb
  475 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/outdated.rb
  476 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/add.rb
  477 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/add_cdn.rb
  478 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/lint.rb
  479 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/list.rb
  480 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tempfile.rb
  481 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/push.rb
  482 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/remove.rb
  483 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/update.rb
  484 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/repo.rb
  485 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/setup.rb
  486 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/create.rb
  487 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/lint.rb
  488 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/which.rb
  489 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/cat.rb
  490 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/edit.rb
  491 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/spec.rb
  492 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/update.rb
  493 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb
  494 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb
  495 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5/lib/cocoapods/deintegrate/gem_version.rb
  496 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5/lib/cocoapods/deintegrator.rb
  497 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5/lib/cocoapods_deintegrate.rb
  498 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5/lib/cocoapods/command/deintegrate.rb
  499 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5/lib/cocoapods_plugin.rb
  500 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0/lib/pod/command/gem_index_cache.rb
  501 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0/lib/pod/command/gem_helper.rb
  502 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0/lib/pod/command/plugins_helper.rb
  503 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0/lib/pod/command/plugins/list.rb
  504 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0/lib/pod/command/plugins/search.rb
  505 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0/lib/pod/command/plugins/create.rb
  506 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0/lib/pod/command/plugins/publish.rb
  507 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0/lib/pod/command/plugins/installed.rb
  508 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0/lib/pod/command/plugins.rb
  509 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods_plugin.rb
  510 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-search-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods-search/command/search.rb
  511 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-search-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods-search/command.rb
  512 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-search-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods_plugin.rb
  513 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0/lib/pod/command/trunk/add_owner.rb
  514 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0/lib/pod/command/trunk/delete.rb
  515 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0/lib/pod/command/trunk/deprecate.rb
  516 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0/lib/pod/command/trunk/info.rb
  517 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0/lib/pod/command/trunk/me.rb
  518 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0/lib/pod/command/trunk/push.rb
  519 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0/lib/pod/command/trunk/register.rb
  520 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0/lib/pod/command/trunk/remove_owner.rb
  521 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0/lib/pod/command/trunk.rb
  522 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0/lib/cocoapods_plugin.rb
  523 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-try-1.2.0/lib/pod/try_settings.rb
  524 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-try-1.2.0/lib/pod/command/try.rb
  525 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-try-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods_plugin.rb
  526 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/tables.rb
  527 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb
  528 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile/dsl.rb
  529 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile/target_definition.rb
  530 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb
  531 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/build_type.rb
  532 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/podfile.rb
  533 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb
  534 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/sandbox.rb
  535 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/headers_store.rb
  536 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/lockfile.rb
  537 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/yaml_helper.rb
  538 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/enc/utf_16le.bundle
  539 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/enc/utf_16be.bundle
  540 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/version.rb
  541 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/pre_install_hooks_context.rb
  542 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/hooks_manager.rb
  543 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/source_provider_hooks_context.rb
  544 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb
  545 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/installation_options.rb
  546 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/podfile_dependency_cache.rb
  547 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/dependency.rb
  548 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/requirement.rb
  549 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/podfile_validator.rb
  550 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb
  551 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/atomos-0.1.3/lib/atomos/version.rb
  552 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/atomos-0.1.3/lib/atomos.rb
  553 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/securerandom.rb
  554 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/case_converter.rb
  555 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object_attributes.rb
  556 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object_dictionary.rb
  557 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object_list.rb
  558 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/constants.rb
  559 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/swift_package_remote_reference.rb
  560 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/swift_package_product_dependency.rb
  561 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/helpers/build_settings_array_settings_by_object_version.rb
  562 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/build_configuration.rb
  563 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/build_file.rb
  564 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/build_phase.rb
  565 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/build_rule.rb
  566 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/configuration_list.rb
  567 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/container_item_proxy.rb
  568 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/helpers/groupable_helper.rb
  569 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/file_reference.rb
  570 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/helpers/file_references_factory.rb
  571 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/group.rb
  572 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/native_target.rb
  573 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/root_object.rb
  574 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/target_dependency.rb
  575 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/reference_proxy.rb


[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

[IMPORTANT]
Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under
DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports.

zsh: abort      pod install
```

Answer (score 4):

Xcode 13, Swift 5, and MACOS Monterey

If you faced this issue

you should do these steps

1- Install Homebrew  from [here](https://brew.sh)

2- Open terminal and type brew install cocoapods

3- Open your Xcode project's directory in terminal and type

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

Then

arch -x86_64 pod install
```

as [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652822)

after it Open you Xcode project.

Answer (score 0):

Just do,

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

Then

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Comment: This simply repeats the answer posted months beforehand.

Answer (score -1):

Seems it's related to Ruby ffi, works as a gen for programmatically loading dynamically-linked native libraries. To solve the issue just run the following commands:

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Comment: This simply repeats previous answers.

Answer (score -1):

Seems it's related to Ruby ffi. Run the following commands:

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Comment: This simply repeats previous answers.